# starting cherrypy properly

Tags: python, http, cherrypy

How do I properly start cherrypy? It worked for me with 3.0 but now I can serve the content but have to start my service everytime I touch the source even though the autoreloader is running.

I already added the `cherrypy.engine.block()` statement, which works but cherrypy stops serving my application then (no answer within the browser, even though it opens the TCP port properly).

So any clue or insight on where or what to look for?

**This is on stdout:**

```
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Bus STARTING<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Serving on 0.0.0.0:8080<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Bus STARTED<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Bus STARTING<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Monitor thread 'Autoreloader' already started.<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor' already started.<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Already serving on 0.0.0.0:8080<br>
[30/Dec/2012:17:05:28] ENGINE Bus STARTED<br>
```

#### How I start it:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(login(), '/', configPath)<br>
cherrypy.tree.mount(reservation(), '/reservation', configPath)<br>
cherrypy.tree.mount(administration(), '/reservation/administration', configPath)<br>
cherrypy.server.socket_host= "0.0.0.0"<br>
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Comment: It *looks* like it's already started.  What specific errors are you seeing on startup?

Comment: i don't see any error - just like i wrote the only way to get it partially working was using only start without the block statement. With it cherrypy wouldnt serve anything, browser would wait forever for a response.

Comment: It's not normal to see STARTED twice. Calling start then block is the right way to go, at least with CherryPy 3.1+

Comment: I'm aware of that fact. But as I said this was the only way to get it working at all, its does serve the desired application. Whereas it doesn't work at all with block added. As you pointed out this is not the proper way to start it, that's why I'm seeking for help!

Comment: No actually it is the proper way. CherryPy offers two simple mechanism: start+block or quickstart (which internally calls the formers). Use block when CherryPy itself is the mainloop, otherwise start is enough indeed.

Comment: Sylvain OK I see, so my problem is still the same, appending block after start doesnt work - cherrypy stops responsing at all! What could be wrong still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was the usage of and old version (actually the latest one linked on their site!) of cherrypy in conjunction with python 3.3. Taking the latest packages from  bitbucket solved this for me!

Answer (score 1):

As Makoto says, it looks like you have started CherryPy twice. Are you calling both engine.start/engine.block along with cherrypy.quickstart? If so, remove one or the other.

Comment: please check the comment i made to makotos answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am only using the Code pasted - no double starting.